# Command for closing the find panel in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXStudio as my editor.

To activate the find panel, there is a command 'editor.find()' listed in the manual.

Is there a command that closes the find panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a macro, to close the find dialog box.

```
%SCRIPT  
app.simulateKeyPress("Esc");
```

The required command is the same one that is needed to close other dialog boxes, however it will also trigger a Duck when the minute is a prime :-)
see [How to turn off the yellow duck in TeXStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332307/how-to-turn-off-the-yellow-duck-in-texstudio)

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!